# Cannot use i.field and by= in same data.table expression

Tags: r, data.table

When joining two data tables and using `by=` in the same expression I get an error any time I attempt to use a column from the inner data.table in j.  I can break things into two separate expressions but that's extra typing - and possibly a performance hit when using large datasets

As an example

```
require(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(k1 = 1:2, k2 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'), v1 = 1:6, key = 'k2')
DT2 <- data.table(k1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'), w1 = 3^(1:3), key = 'k1')

DT1[DT2, sum(v1*w1), by=k1]    # fails complaining about being unable to find w1
DT1[DT2, sum(v1*i.w1), by=k1]  # also fails with the same error
DT1[DT2][, sum(v1*w1), by=k1]  # works
```

With small data sets the join then group approach is fine.  For datasets with many columns, however, creating an interim result with all the columns of both data.tables is a significant load (my actual data tables are roughly 1-2 Gb in size).

While I could could shrink the number of columns involved by doing

```
DT1[DT2[,.(k1, w1)]][,sum(v1*w1),by=k1]
```

that eliminates one of the great values of data.tables - not having to constantly specify the relationship between datasets.  It also requires me to remember to specific a column in two different places each time I do a join.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Is there any reason they need to stay as 2 separate data.tables? Seems like joining them into a single data.table solves your problem.

Comment: I don't understand the complaint. In the both failures teh j-expression has variables that are not in the datatable being referenced.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think we could bring more consistency to `by`.. Could you please file an issue linking to this post on the github data.table page? Thanks.

Comment: @42- `data.table` in general has join-inherited scope. So `DT1[DT2, sum(v1*w1)]` works as expected; the complaint is that combining this with `by` caused an issue.

Comment: @JeremyS: in my real-world application the tables have an M:N relationship.  They also have value independently.  Merging the two would require constant use of unique(DT) when I wanted to do analysis on one set.  It would also push my machine's memory capacity to the limit.

Comment: @Arun: done (issue #1519)

Comment: Doing it your way though includes the merge step, so if you need to do something like that, say 5 times, then your approach merges them 5 separate times which is not very efficient.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a bug was filed and resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Possible [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824705/using-on-and-by-to-compute-a-new-variable-from-two-data-tables) with link to data.table feature request [#733](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733).