# Using `on` and `by` to compute a new variable from two data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

How come I cannot use `by` when computing a new variable by from two `data.tables` following a merge?

Example datasets:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

# Example datasets.
dt1 <- data.table(id=1:10,
                  var=rnorm(10))

dt2 <- data.table(id=c(2, 4, 5, 6, 8),
                  color=sample(1:2, 5, replace=TRUE),
                  group=sample(c("a", "b"), 5, replace=TRUE))

# Join on ID.
dt1[dt2, on="id"]

#    id        var     newVar color group
# 1:  2  0.1836433  0.3672866     2     a
# 2:  4  1.5952808  1.5952808     1     a
# 3:  5  0.3295078  0.6590155     2     a
# 4:  6 -0.8204684 -0.8204684     1     b
# 5:  8  0.7383247  0.7383247     1     a
```

It seems `group` is available as a variable after the join. Now compute new variable from `dt1` and `dt2` variables (using `by`).

```
dt1[dt2, mean(var*color), on="id", by="group"]
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'group' not found
```

Doesn't work because `group` is not found, even though `var` and `color` are visible and come from different datasets? This works:

```
dt1[dt2, mean(var*color), on="id"]
# [1] 0.5078879
```

Why is `color` from `dt2` available for computing a new variable, but `group`, also from `dt2`, is not? I've tried with a modified example where `group` is in `dt1`, but then `color` is not found.

Comment: I have a feeling that your example is not correct for the `by=group` you want to do.

Comment: @akrun, you're right, I forgot that I wanted `mean(var*color)`. Modified the example.

Comment: I think it is a two step process, `dt1[dt2, on = "id"][, mean(var*color), by = group]`

Comment: That's indeed how I am doing it at the moment. Is there any reason why it can't be implemented as `on` and `by` in a single process? If not I might open a feature request on GH since part of `data.table`'s goal is a short syntax.
Not mentioned in the example, but I would like to store the new variable in the original dataset.
Currently: `dt1 <- dt1[dt2, on = "id"][, newVar := mean(var*color), by = group]`
New: `dt1[dt2, newVar := mean(var*color), on="id", by="group"]`

Comment: I am not sure about why it can't be implemented.  You can open a feature request after a couple of days (in case somebody comes up with a solution).

Comment: Probably this one: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733

Comment: @Frank Yes, after wading through the comments on GH, it seems like that request would solve my problem.